# How to detect click event on any checkbox on a page using jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery

How can I detect that a click event is fired on any `checkbox` on a page using `jQuery`? Please also note that on page load, may be checkbox(s) is/are not created but could be created on request. So HTML DOM will be updated in that fashion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(":checkbox").on("click", function(){

// your work

} );
```

also see **[bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)**

**[delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)**

**[live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)**

reference **[On](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

Answer (score 2):

TRy this

```
$( document ).on( "click", "input[type='checkbox']", function() {
  alert( "check box clicked" );
});
```

Comment: Binding to the document creates for a bunch of unnecessary event listening. It's why jQuery's `.live()` function was phased out.

Comment: You're answer helped in debug. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$(":checkbox").on("click", function(){

// ALL YOUR STUFF

} )
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a function `checkboxClick()` as -

```
function checkboxClick() {
    // ---
    // your code goes here
    // ...
}
```

Now for every checkbox (even when you add them dynamically) add attribute `onclick` like

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:checkboxClick();" class="checkbox" />
```

Note : Since javascript works on existing dom elements, even if you do something like `jQuery(".checkbox").click(function() {...});`, it wont work on dynamicically added elements

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', ':checkbox', function() {
//your code
});
```